# clamd.sock permisson denied

Tags: postfix, clamav

Clamav is running as clamscan user

But I get a permisson denied error:

```
Apr  6 20:23:48 nais2 clamsmtpd: 100003: CLAMAV: couldn't connect to: /var/run/clamd.scan/clamd.sock: Permission denied
```

But:

```
ls -lah /var/run/clamd.scan/clamd.sock
drwx--x---. 3 clamscan clamscan 60 Apr  6 20:28 ..
```

and clamscan has permission to the directory.

Answer (score 4):

`/var/run/clamd.scan/clamd.sock` should be a socket file, not a directory.  `clamscan` will create the socket file when it starts.

Where your filemask looks like `drwx--x---`, it should be `srwx--x---`.

Remove that directory, and restart your service, to let `clamd` create the socket file.

Comment: after removing and restarting now the error is CLAMAV: couldn't connect to: /var/run/clamd.scan/clamd.sock: No such file or directory

Comment: ClamAddress: /var/run/clamd.scan/clamd.sock i have given this in the .conf file

Comment: @naishu - I'm not sure what .conf file you put `ClamAddress` in.  In clamd.conf, you should likely have the line `LocalSocket /var/run/clamd.scan/clamd.sock`